# Compose view recomposes when an item's property changes inside mutableStateListOf but not when the list gets transformed

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to convert a mutableStateList to another type of mutableStateList, which I'm trying to render using Compose View elements. Here is the code snippet I have.

```
// MyViewModel.kt

private val _myOriginalList = mutableStateListOf<MyClass>()
val myOriginalList: List<MyClass> = _myOriginalList

fun myProcessor(uris: List<String>) {

      val tempList = uris.map { MyClass(uri = it) }
      _myOriginalList.addAll(tempList)

     tempList.map { item ->
            myProcessor(item) { resultUrl ->
                 item.url = resultUrl
            }
     }
}
```

My Compose function uses myOriginalList to render components:

```
fun MyComposeView(myOriginalList: List<MyClass>) {
        LazyRow {
              items(items = myOriginalList) {

                   // UI components... <-- This is able to pickup the `url` automatically as well as update the UI when new items get added/deleted. Why???
             }
        }

        val anotherList = remember(myOriginalList) {
                myOriginalList.map { item -> MyAnotherClass(item.uri, item.url) }.toMutableStateList()  }
        }

       LazyColumn {
            items(anotherList) {
                 // UI components. <--- This doesn't get recomposed when `url` gets updated. It doesn't even update the UI when elements get added/deleted Why??

           }
      }

}
```

Things I have tried:

**Approach 1:**

```
@Parcelize
data class MyClass(
    val url: @RawValue MutableState<String?> = mutableStateOf(null),
    var uri: String? = null
)
```

**Approach 2:**

```
// In my compose view

LaunchedEffect(myOriginalList) {
    anotherList.clear()
    anotherList.addAll(
      myOriginalList.map { item -> MyAnotherClass(item.uri, item.url) }.toMutableStateList()
    )
}
```

**Approach 3:**

```
// MyViewModel.kt

for(uri in uris) {
    _myOriginalList.indexOfFirst { it.uri == uri }.takeIf { it != -1 }?.let {
        myProcessor(_myOriginalList[it]) { url -> 
            _myOriginalList[it].url.value = url
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

- `anotherList` must be a `MutableList<MyAnotherClass>`
- The UI should recompose when the `result` gets set OR new item gets added/deleted to `myOriginalList`

Comment: I strongly suspect the issue is that `remember` call.  Does it work correctly with that removed?

Comment: Tried removing just the key `(myOriginalList)` and also tried removing the whole `remember(myOriginalList)`. No luck

Comment: Hmmm, that's quite surprising, given that it would actually be reading the state member in each item within the `MyComposeView` composable itself.  I'm not sure what's wrong, sorry.

Comment: Edit: My bad. It seems to pickup the change after removing `remember`. I just realized one of my Library State method is using a `remember { }`. Is there an easier way to force recompose, without removing `remember`?

Comment: Not with the way your code is written (because `anotherList` is derived from `myOriginalList`).  Why do you want the `remember` there?  It's only serving to prevent `anotherList` from being regenerated when it needs to be.

Comment: It's my library that was using `remember`. I didn't realize `anotherList` was getting converted again to `internalList` using remember. When i applied your suggestion and changed my library to `internalList = remember (anotherList) { anotherList }` it started working like magic. Thank you, Ryan!

Answer (score 0):

In Compose, recomposition happens when the state you're observing (using `remember`, `rememberUpdatedState`, `mutableStateOf`, etc.) changes. In your code, when you use `myOriginalList` directly, Compose recognizes it as a dependency and automatically recomposes when `myOriginalList` changes. However, in the case of `anotherList`, the transformation from `myOriginalList` to `anotherList` happens outside the `@Composable` function, so Compose doesn't detect changes.

To make `anotherList` update correctly when `myOriginalList` changes, you can leverage Compose's `DerivedState` to create a dynamic transformation and observe it in your composable function.

First, you need to create a derived state based on `myOriginalList`. This can be achieved by using `derivedStateOf` or `produceDerivedState` from Compose's core library.

Here's an example using `derivedStateOf`:

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.runtime.derivedStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.rememberUpdatedState

@Composable
fun MyComposeView(myOriginalList: List<MyClass>) {
    val updatedOriginalList by rememberUpdatedState(myOriginalList)
    
    // Create a derived state based on myOriginalList
    val anotherList by remember(updatedOriginalList) {
        derivedStateOf {
            updatedOriginalList.map { item -> MyAnotherClass(item.uri, item.url) }
        }
    }

    LazyRow {
        items(items = updatedOriginalList) {
            // UI components for myOriginalList
        }
    }

    LazyColumn {
        items(anotherList) {
            // UI components for anotherList
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when `myOriginalList` changes, Compose will automatically recompose `anotherList`, and the UI components using `anotherList` will be updated accordingly.

Note that `rememberUpdatedState` is used to ensure that `myOriginalList` itself doesn't get recreated during recomposition, which can lead to recomposition loops.

Comment: I tried using `derivedStateOf`. When items get added or deleted it works as expected. But, when the item.url is set, it doesn't seem to update.  When you say "`myOriginalList` itself doesn't get recreated during recomposition", are you referring to the approach that Ryan mentioned in the comment? `val anotherList = myOriginalList.map { item -> MyAnotherClass(item.uri, item.url) }.toMutableStateList()  }` ?